# Validate/sanitise input before reaching the Guards in Nest.js

Tags: javascript, validation, nestjs, sanitization

I am using Nest.js to set up a simple signup handle. The request holds three values, name, email, and password. I am planning to run a DB cross-check in a Guard, to see if a similar user already exists. Then only the request reaches the route handler. But I am confused about where to set up the validation/sanitizer so that the inputs are sanitized before reaching the Guard.

Comment: Why do you want to use a guard on a sign up route?

Comment: Just wanted to know if any validation/sanitization is available within guards.

Comment: Nope. Guards run before interceptors which run before pipes. If you want validation in a guard, you have to do it yourself